# How to blank out the EditorFor input elements created when views are created with scaffold.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a viewmodel like this:

```
public class M_Master
{
    public string SUPWH { get; set; }

    public string STKGL { get; set; }

    public string SALGL { get; set; }

    public string COSGL { get; set; }


    public decimal ROQ { get; set; }

    public int MIN { get; set; }

    public int MAX { get; set; }

    public int LT { get; set; }

    public string PRODSPEC { get; set; }

    public string REMK1 { get; set; }

    public string REMK2 { get; set; }

    public decimal openingQty { get; set; }
    public decimal openingAmt { get; set; }
    public decimal onHandQty { get; set; }
    public decimal ytdReceiptQty { get; set; }

}
```

Then I use this ViewModel to create a View. So the view looks something like the below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>INV_Master</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PROD, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PROD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PROD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WH, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WH, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WH, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DESCR, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DESCR, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DESCR, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I realise is that when I visit the page/view, the html `input`fields by default are filled in with values like 0 for those properties in the ViewMoel which are int, decimal, datetime. How do I make sure that all the `input` fields by default are empty ?

Comment: change `int` to `int?` ?

Comment: Change those non-nullable types to nullable, e.g. `int` => `int?`, `decimal` => `decimal?`, `DateTime` => `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nullable types like int?, decimal?, and DateTime?.  When objects are instantiated, each property will be initialized to the datatype default.  Int defaults to 0, and int? defaults to null.  And so on.  You can still put a [Required] on the property to ensure they are entered by the user before being posted back to the server.